# Find duplicate rows in Excel table and sum rows

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I have an Excel table whose unique key is the combination of Para1, Para2 and Para3:

```
Para1   Para2   Para3  Value1    Value2   Value3 
  A         B       C       1         2       3
  A         E       F       4         6       4
  A         B       C       5         3       7
  P         Q       R       4         2       4
```

I want to find the duplicates and SUM the values, so the expected output is:

```
Para1   Para2   Para3  Value1    Value2   Value3 
  A         B       C       6         5       10
  A         E       F       4         6       4
  P         Q       R       4         2       4
```

Is there a way to group the data get the SUM?

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the columns 1,2 & 3. Then remove the duplicates and put a SUMIFS function in the Value columns.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Para1` is in A1, insert a column on the left that concatenates the key elements:

```
=B1&C1&D1
```

and copy down to suit. Sort your data by that column and apply Subtotal At each change in: `Para1Para2Para3`, Use function: Sum, Add subtotal to: check `Value1`, `Value2`, `Value3`, Replace current subtotals and Summary below data, OK.

Filter ColumnA, Text Filters, Contains..., `tot`, OK. In B4 enter:

```
=B3
```

copy across to D4 and B4:D4 down to suit. (Select All) in ColumnA, select all cells, Copy, Paste Special..., Values, OK over the top. Filter ColumnA again to select Does Not Contain..., `tot`, OK and delete all visible except the labels. Delete ColumnA and last row. Select all cells and in Subtotal select <kbd>Remove All</kbd>.